# Partition $nk$ objects up to $\frac{\binom{nk}{m}}{n\binom{k}{m}}$ times, each time making $k$-subsets, so that no combination of $m$ is ever repeated

Tags: permutations, algorithms, combinations, cyclic-groups, set-partition

What is an **efficient** algorithm to partition $nk$ objects a total of up to $\frac{\binom{nk}{m}}{n\binom{k}{m}}$ times, each time making subsets of size exactly $k$? The additional constraint is that no subset of size $m$ is ever repeated within any of the $k$-subsets (where $m$ is a given constant and $m\leq k$). Obviously, this is only possible if $\frac{\binom{nk}{m}}{n\binom{k}{m}}$ is an integer. Even if this is not always possible, I am still interested to know an algorithm that is able to accomplish the **maximum** number of successful partitions.

For example, if $n=k=3$ and $m=2$, then we have $9$ objects and we want to partition into groups of size $3$, such that no pair of objects is ever repeated in any $3$-subset. For this example, it turns out we can hit all $\binom{nk}{m}=\binom{3(3)}{2}=36$ pair combinations in $\frac{\binom{nk}{m}}{n\binom{k}{m}}=\frac{\binom{3(3)}{2}}{3\binom{3}{2}}=4$ partitions. For this small example, inefficient algorithms like the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133347/how-to-split-a-list-into-subsets-with-no-repeating-elements-in-python work. An example solution is:

> ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9))
>
> ((1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9))
>
> ((1, 5, 9), (2, 6, 7), (3, 4, 8))
>
> ((1, 6, 8), (2, 4, 9), (3, 5, 7))

But I want to be able to solve larger sized problems (e.g. $n=17,k=3,m=2$) and at least be able to maximize the number of valid partitions (even if a full solution is impossible).

Comment: When $m=k$ it is possible to do this so that each $k$-set occurs once, by [Braranyai's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baranyai%27s_theorem).  There is a proof of this in the last chapter of [Van Lindt and Wilson](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/course-in-combinatorics/84B89574496561D5E3A960863B85E4B7) that's essentially an algorithm.  Perhaps you can modify it.

Comment: I found a proof of Baranyai's theorem at https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/Graphs%2C%20Networks%20and%20Algorithms%20%282nd%20ed.%29%20%5BJungnickel%202004-11-29%5D.pdf See section 7.6